# HTML publish latex block images

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, org-babel, html

I am trying to export a latex tikzpicture, like the following to html:

```
#+begin_src latex :exports results :results raw file :file ex.png :output-dir ../img/
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw node[circle, draw] (a) {$a$}
      node[circle, draw, right of = a] (b) {$b$}
      node[circle, draw, below of = a] (c) {$c$}
      node[circle, draw, below of = b] (d) {$d$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
#+end_src
```

If I export with `org-export-dispatch` to HTML file, I flawlessly obtain the desired html. If I however, `org-html-publish-to-html` with:

```
emacs -Q --script build-site.el
```

Then I obtain the following error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Attempt to calculate the dpi of a non-graphic disp...")
  signal(error ("Attempt to calculate the dpi of a non-graphic disp..."))
  error("Attempt to calculate the dpi of a non-graphic disp...")
  org--get-display-dpi()
  org-create-formula-image("\\begin{tikzpicture}\n  \\draw node[circle, draw] (a)..." "../img/ex.png" (:foreground default :background default :scale 1.0 :html-foreground "Black" :html-background "Transparent" :html-scale 1.0 :matchers ("begin" "$1" "$" "$$" "\\(" "\\[")) t)
```

My `build-site.el` configuration is the following:
https://github.com/dcguim/dgpage/blob/main/build-site.el

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's probably a bug that you should report with `M-x org-submit-report-bug`.

As a workaround, `org--get-display-dpi` is a pretty simple function, so you can probably replace it with your own. Try adding this to your `build-site.el` file:

```el
(with-eval-after-load 'org

(defun org--get-display-dpi ()
  "Get the DPI of the display.
The function assumes that the display has the same pixel width in
the horizontal and vertical directions."
  (if (display-graphic-p)
      (round (/ (display-pixel-height)
        (/ (display-mm-height) 25.4)))
    96.0)))
```

replacing the `96.0` with whatever result calling `M-: (org--get-display-dpi)` returns in your interactive session. That will avoid raising the error and will give you the same dpi value as before, allowing the creation of the image to proceed.